# npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY when i run vue create project

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, npm-install, vue-cli

when I run `vue create project`
I have this error:

```
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! Verification failed while extracting node-notifier@^5.4.2:
npm ERR! Verification failed while extracting node-notifier@^5.4.2:
npm ERR! sha1-DLwaKw9lhJO0Ald1oTrZOOlgke8= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-DLwaKw9lhJO0Ald1oTrZOOlgke8= but got sha512-rCRh2ViyPFxaWIPrbMQGOXoOB13VcwRPbgt2rZ8VLRJDs2zY71jPHoy1mrG2+yH3nRfgezLwGUbYq2V9d2UksQ== sha1-tPoTWxYZZzXidkjUdIfI/IG/QLE=. (524452 bytes)
```

after I select the preset and some packages are installed the error is shown.

I tried to run  `npm cache verify` several times but when I run it the error is shown with another package.

I also tried  `npm cache clean --force` but the error is still.

Any ideas?

**NOTE:** I created many projects with vue but the problem started after I reinstalled my operating system (Linux Ubuntu 20.10).

Comment: did you try `npm config set Strict-ssl false` ?

Comment: I tried now and it works, can you tell me what happened. Thanks

Comment: Explained in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly one or more package(s) certificates expired. `Strict-ssl` forces the package source to be it has ssl certificate. Default value of `Strict-ssl` is `true`. With this setting, you cannot enforce the package has an ssl certificate :

`npm config set Strict-ssl false`

Answer (score 1):

This also can happen when using an old node version (8.11.1 for me). I switched to version 14 and it worked